# How do I make sudo remember my password for longer?

Tags: sudo, password

How do I make `sudo` remember my password for longer so that I don't have to keep typing it? I do not want to `sudo su` and execute commands as root all the time.

I am on Arch Linux and have tried to google this but I get examples to change my password, which is not what I'm after.

Comment: Point of order, `sudo` does not "remember your password" so much as it remembers your *session* -- pam_sudo remembers that you authenticated correctly in that particular console session and retains that flag for `passwd_timeout` seconds.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is `timestamp_timeout` option in your `/etc/sudoers`. You can set up this option to number of minutes. After that time it will ask for password again. More info in `man sudoers`.

And make sure you edit your `sudoers` file using visudo, which checks your syntax and which will not leave you with wrong configuration and inaccessible `sudo`.

Comment: If you rely rely hate passwords, then you can configure `sudoers` so that you do not need one. You can also do this for just some individual commands / users.

Answer (score 27):

There is a `timestamp_timeout` option in your /etc/sudoers...

Example: to get password remembered for 5 hours

```
Defaults        timestamp_timeout=300
```

Comment: I think this is actually what i was after, the passwd_timeout is only how long it takes for the password prompt to stay up with no input

Comment: if that's true can you please accept this one instead? the current situation is misleading in that case

Answer (score 1):

open **/etc/sudoers** for editing in vi editor

```
sudo visudo
```

enter your password

in vi editor to go to the end of the line and go into edit mode type `A` and **ENTER**

add this line where `300` is the new timeout in minutes.

```
Defaults        timestamp_timeout=300
```

to exit vi edit mode type **ESC** button

to save file type `:w` and **ENTER**

to exit type `:q` and **ENTER**