# How to setting Ubuntu sudo password dialog for every 1 hours

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, sudo, su

i work on my personal Desktop that no one touch it.

so, i mean, duration password needs to be entered again after entering corect pasword.

[image]

how to do that? thx

Comment: Do you want to change the password or chance the duration after which the password needs to be entered again? You ask for the first, but second makes more sense.

Comment: As Philippos pointed, you probably ask for extending period of sudo asking for entering password. If you ask how to change "sudo password" -> sudo is not user, so password cannot be changed for "sudo user". Sudo is the program for elevating rights for normal users so they can do thins as they are privileged users.

Comment: It sounds like you're *probably* asking [How do I make sudo remember my password for longer?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/216891/how-do-i-make-sudo-remember-my-password-for-longer)

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: @philipo  : yes that what i mean

Comment: @damir : yes that what i mean

Comment: @steel : thanks

Answer (score 0):

The steps are:

1. Run `sudo visudo` (or edit `/etc/sudoers` in some other way);
2. Add at the end of file `Defaults:USER timestamp_timeout=XX`, where `USER` is your username and `XX` the number of minutes to which you want to set the timeout (max 99);
3. Save and close; I would recommend starting a new session before testing that it works.

Comment: thank work like charm..

Comment: You're welcome. Maybe you can mark the answer as correct for me?

Comment: how to mark corect answer i dont know

Comment: There should be a link to "Accept" my answer. Only you, as the Asker, sees this link.

Comment: @mobagenie There is a greyed-out tick to the left of the answer that you can tick to mark the answer as "accepted".  You may at any later on accept another answer, should there appear an answer that is better for you.

Comment: @AnthonyKelly : you mean this answer is useful ^ ? i dont have reputation sorry :(

Comment: @Kusalananda : i cant tick "this answer useful" no reputation :(

Comment: @mobagenie Not the up or down-arrow, the tick: ✔️